# Why prefer passing named function reference as prop to event listener over inline anonymous function?

Tags: reactjs

Recently started React, and came across this approach where we can add event listeners to our jsx elements using props.

`<button onClick={[function-here]}>Click here</button>`

Next, it was suggested to use named function reference to pass as prop rather than passing an inline arrow function.

I searched why is it so, and got to know that inline functions are recreated on re-renders, and hence passing them as prop, would cause unnecessary re-renders of child components. Here I got confused since I know if parent is re-rendered, then child would be re-rendered too. Also, how does update in prop cause re-render in child component, if I am using function based components approach?

My code is as follows:

**Inline function passing approach**

```
import React from 'react';

import ExpenseDate from './ExpenseDate';
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import './ExpenseItem.css';

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card className='expense-item'>
      <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
      <div className='expense-item__description'>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={()=>{console.log("Hello World")}}>Change title</button>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

**Named function reference approach**

```
import React from 'react';

import ExpenseDate from './ExpenseDate';
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import './ExpenseItem.css';

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {

  function changeTitle(){
    console.log("Hello");
  }

  return (
    <Card className='expense-item'>
      <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
      <div className='expense-item__description'>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={changeTitle}>Change title</button>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Comment: There is a clear advantage in class components to avoid redefining the function on each render cycle. And for functional components, the advantage is still there if you want it, where you can leverage hooks like [`useCallback()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) to cache your function definitions and similarly avoid unnecessary cycles.

Comment: Could you please explain the 2nd point.

Comment: Wording there is a bit misleading, there are ways to prevent a child from rerendering if a parent rerenders. Please read [this](https://whereisthemouse.com/react-components-when-do-children-re-render).

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are functionally different.

The first one calls `console.log` *whenever the component is rendered*:

```js
{/* `onClick` does nothing; it was assigned return value of `console.log` */}
<button onClick={console.log("Hello World")}>Change title</button>
```

The second one calls `changeTitle` *whenever the button is clicked*:

```js
{/* `onClick` calls `changeTitle` */}
<button onClick={changeTitle}>Change title</button>
```

You may have been trying to compare against an inline anonymous function like the following?:

```js
<button onClick={() => { console.log("Hello World"); }}>Change title</button>
```

You seem to have heard the advice that "creating functions on every render is bad." However, JavaScript is fast. Creating functions is fast. Unless this component is rendering hundreds of times per second, the creation of some extra functions is going to have negligible impact on performance.

Comment: My bad. I have updated the inline function now, and yes you got the point. Thanks!